# Groovy's eachFile() returns only the first item found when used in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-groovy

The following statement (which outputs all files and/or folder names found in a particular directory)

```
new File(".").eachFile{file ->
    println file
}
```

behaves differently when used in Jenkins pipeline - i.e. its output is always only the first file (or directory) found.

Has anyone a clue why?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to list all files like:

```
new File(".").listFiles().sort{ it.name }.each { def f ->
    println f.name
}
```

Comment: Thx, This works in Jenkins if omitting the name property inside sorting